# No suitable method for add

Tags: java, arraylist

I am running the following code. But I am getting this error when I do `currentSumPairs.add(sumPair)`

```
List<List<Integer>> quadrupules = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
Map<Integer, List<int[]>> pairs = new HashMap<Integer, List<int[]>>();      
List<int[]> sumPair = new ArrayList<int[]>();

sumPair.add(new int[]{1, 2});

if (pairs.containsKey(0)) {
    List<int[]> currentSumPairs = pairs.get(0);
    currentSumPairs.add(sumPair);
    pairs.put(0, currentSumPairs);
} else {    
    pairs.put(0, sumPair);
}
```

This gives the following error:

> no suitable method found for add(List)

Comment: You're trying to add a `List<int[]>` to a `List<int[]>` not a `List<List<int[]>>`. Therefore it gives that error.

Comment: `currentSumPairs` is of type `List<int[]>` and `sumPair` is of type `List<int[]>`. Do you want to all `addAll`?

Answer (score 0):

`sumPair` is declared as `List<int[]>`. `currentSumPairs` is also declared as `List<int[]>`, which means it's a `List` containing `int[]` (`int` array) instances. So you can't put `sumPair` into `currentSumPairs`, it's not of type `int[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Since sumPair is a list, it should be

```
currentSumPairs.addAll(sumPair);
```

Comment: **If** the goal is to add all entries; you should say that, since the OP hasn't said that's their goal.

Answer (score 0):

The `currentSumPairs` and `sumPair` are of types `List<int[]>`.
The `.add()` method is expecting `int[]`. You can't add `List<int[]>` in place of `int[]` they aren't the same.

I think you are looking for the `addAll(...)` method.

```
currentSumPairs.addAll(sumPair);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Small addition**

The usage generics with arrays, such as `List<int[]>`, is badly compatible therefore is highly discouraged because it may lead to disastrous results.
This may cause all types of mistakes and fails that you really do not want to encounter.

As Joshua Bloch mentions in his book ["Effective Java"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134685997), any combinations of arrays and generics are unwanted at least, because they have substantial differences.

> First, arrays are covariant.[..] Generics, by contrast, are invariant.

**E.g.**

Speaking of arrays, this is a totally legit piece of code and it will compile smoothly. But it fails at runtime if you try to persist `SubObject` in the array.

```
    SuperObject[] arrayOfCustomObjects = new SubObject[1] // Fails at runtime, throws ArrayStoreException
```

Generics, in this case `List`, being invariant won't let to create a list instance of a subtype, failing at compile-time. It must be exactly the same type.

```
   List<SuperObject> listOfCustomObjects = new ArrayList<SubObject> // Won't compile, must be the same types, fail-fast
```

> Arrays are *reified*. This means that arrays know and enforce their element type at runtime.[..]
>
> Generics, by contrast, are implemented by erasure. This means that they enforce their type constraints only at compile time and discard(or erase) their element type information at runtime. Erasure is what allowed generic types to interoperate freely with legacy code that didn't use generics, ensuring a smooth transition to generics in Java 5.
>
> Because of these fundamental differences, arrays, and generics do not mix well.
>   For example, it is illegal to create an array of a generic type, a parameterized type, or a type parameter.
>             **Joshua Bloch, "Effective Java"(3 edition)**

For more information, checkout ["Effective Java"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134685997).